# Cassandra multinode cluster setup issue

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to setup a Cassandra multinode cluster on CentOS 7 with OpenJDK.

I have 2 Nodes:

- node1 10.99.189.49
- node2 10.99.189.50

I have done following things till now:

1. Downloaded the tarball of Cassandra from PlanetCassandra site
2. Extracted it in Documents folder.
3. Created all the necessary directories (data/saved_cache, data/commitlog, data/data) as mentioned in the YAML file.

And I have made 3 changes in my conf/cassandra.yaml file as follows:

On node 10.99.189.49:

```
seeds: "10.99.189.49" 
listen_address: 10.99.189.49
rpc_address: 10.99.189.49
```

On node 10.99.189.50:

```
seeds: "10.99.189.49" 
listen_address: 10.99.189.50
rpc_address: 10.99.189.50
```

Now I run cassandra on node 10.99.189.49
and then I run cassandra on the other node.

Cassandra starts normally on both the nodes 
BUT
when I do:

```
bin/nodetool status
```

I can see only one node in it.

Can anyone point what I am doing wrong or missing something?

Comment: Are seeing any evidence in the logs that the nodes are talking to each other? or, Are then obvious errors in the logs?

Comment: Also make sure that `cluster_name` is the same.

Comment: @Aaron Yes the cluster_name is same.

Comment: @mikea 
No there are no obivous errors in the logs :(

Comment: Are you sure the nodes can see each other, and that all necessary ports (7000, 7199, 9042) are open between them?  From .49, try `telnet 10.99.189.50 7000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So I started adding tips in the comments, and for my 3rd time around I thought I'd start putting them all together in an actual answer.*

DataStax does a pretty good job documenting how this should work.  Make sure that you've gone through these docs (specifically the first one) and that you're following all the steps:

- [Initializing a multiple node cluster (single data center)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html)
- [Adding nodes to an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html)

In addition to everything you have mentioned above, make sure that the `cluster_name` is the same on each node.

I find it easier to make this work using the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.  Set that in your **cassandra.yaml** on each node:

```
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Then make sure that each of your nodes is specifying the same default data center in the **cassandra-rackdc.properties** file:

```
dc=DC1
```

Get your first node (.49) up-and-running.  Verify it with `nodetool status`.

Also verify that you have [opened the necessary ports in your firewall](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html).  From .49, try `telnet`ing your way to the other node on the ports that Cassandra requires.  I recommend 7000, as that is the port for non-SSL inter-node communication.

```
telnet 10.99.189.50 7000
```

Once you're sure all that works and everything is configured properly, *then* bring up .50.  I remember reading that you should wait at least 2 minutes before bringing up another node, so do that just to be on the safe side.  Tail the logs to make sure it handshakes with the other node, or to see any errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/cassandra/system.log
```

*Notes: Your log location may vary.  I'm assuming you're running 2.2.  If you are using a different version of Cassandra, please indicate it.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On both node use

```
seeds: "10.99.189.49,10.99.189.50"
```

and also restart both node cassandra

Comment: but I dont want the other node to be a seed

so why should I use this??
Can you please let me know the reason?